# docker compose not starting both application

Tags: reactjs, spring-boot, docker, docker-compose

I have below folder structure for my application.

- rootFolder

  - docker-compose.yml
  - rest-api-project

    - Dockerfile
  - react-ui-project

    - Dockerfile

rest-api-project is running on 7070 port & react-ui-project running on 8080 port.

**Dockerfile for rest-api-project**

```
FROM java:8-jdk-alpine

COPY ./Rest-Api/target/Rest-Api-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar /usr/app/

WORKDIR /usr/app

RUN sh -c 'touch Rest-Api-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar'
EXPOSE 7070:7070

ENTRYPOINT ["java","-jar","Rest-Api-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar"]
```

Dockerfile for react-ui-project

```
FROM node:lts-alpine as build
RUN mkdir /react-ui
WORKDIR /react-ui
COPY package.json .
RUN npm install
COPY . .
EXPOSE 8080:8080
CMD ["npm","start"]
```

**docker-compose.yml**

```
version: "3.0"
services:
    reactui:
        build:            
            dockerfile: Dockerfile
            context: ./react-ui-project
        ports:
            - "8080:8080"
    restapi:
        build:
            dockerfile: Dockerfile
            context: ./rest-api-project
        ports:
            - "7070:7070"
```

I am running `docker-compose up` command.
Both application start normally.
When I try `localhost:8080` in my hose browser, I do not see react application running.
But If I try with `localhost:7070` then I get sample response from rest-api-project.

I could not figure out why react application on `localhost:8080` is not showing up.

Comment: are you sure that your app is listening on 8080? is it using `0.0.0.0` or `127.0.0.1`?

Comment: It start on localhost. I am using webpack to start react application. As I can see that in logs it start on localhost:8080 and I have not provided any host under devServer for webpack

Comment: can you change that to `0.0.0.0`

Comment: 0.0.0.0 is not working.

Comment: is there something in the logs of the `reactui`? do you see that is listening on "0.0.0.0:8080"?

Comment: Works now, rebuild whole image again.
Made 0.0.0.0 instead of localhost webpack.

Comment: thanks for the update. I added my comment above as an answer - I'll appreciate it if you can accept it / upvote if that what solved your problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the Dockerfiles, change `EXPOSE 7070:7070` to `EXPOSE 7070` and `EXPOSE 8080:8080` to `EXPOSE 8080`. The port binding should be done in docker-compose (as you have) or in the run command.

Comment: Applied changes. localhost:7070 is working, but localhost:8080 is not working.

Comment: Are you sure your restapi is listening on port 7070? It is quite common for servers to run on port 8080. Maybe you can try exposing the port 8080 in restapi Dockerfile and binding the restapi ports in the docker-compose.yml as "7070:8080".

Comment: Works now, rebuild again and it works perfectly.

Answer (score 1):

In order to get access from external interfaces, you need to make sure that the host is set to `"0.0.0.0"` instead of `"localhost"` or `"127.0.0.1"` (which is the right way to work in a development environment for security reasons).

In other words, just ensure your app is listening on:

```
0.0.0.0:8080
```

Comment: Done couple of changes. One provided by you and other by @Greg.